# Reading a QR code and deploying an application using Unity and Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens

I'm beginner with HoloLens and Unity engine. Last days, I've found an application that can be read QR codes. In there can be encoded information like URLs, images, mp3 audio, etc. At the same time, I was wondering if it is possible through reading QR code launching different kind of applications using unity engine. For example, if I read one QR code executing this game with the HoloLens, with another QR code another game. I did not study game engineer or informatics, therefore I don't if it is possible to implement it.

Comment: It is possible to read a QR code within a unity application and start a process. It may not be fully possible in Hololens as I think the .NET version on UWP does not have Process class (not 100% sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can, but you need to specify your requeriments very carefully.
First of all QR Code reading is actually an image processing. For image processing you need 2 object: An "Digital image"  and a "processor". (In your case Hololens Camera and Hololens processor)

Basicly when you open an application in your holo lens which has qr reading capabilities, It just uses hololens's camera for "digital image" and then with the algorithm in the application it just convert to **qr code to** a **data**.(for exmple url or a general path to an application on the hololens etc.)

After that,Applicaiton uses that data to for opening new applications or use it in own scope. It depends on the privilages of application in the Hololens Operating system.

If I were you,I will not use unity for the qr code reading. If I will use unity, ı will not make diffrent apps for diffrerent games so after read qr code ı just open diffrent part of the same application.